# How to control clang default include path

Tags: visual-studio, clang, llvm

My copy of clang tries to include Visual Studio header files, this is the output of `clang -v hello.cc`

```
clang version 9.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git 4f93b8b56f5982d19b8b55b8c575887c17e15588) 
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc 
Thread model: posix 
InstalledDir: D:\llvm-project\build\Release\bin 
 "D:\\llvm-project\\build\\Release\\bin\\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.21.27702 -emit-obj -mrelax-all
-mincremental-linker-compatible -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hello.cc -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -v -resource-dir "D:\\llvm-project\\build\\Release\\lib\\clang\\9.0.0"
-internal-isystem "D:\\llvm-project\\build\\Release\\lib\\clang\\9.0.0\\include"
-internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\ATLMFC\\include"
-internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\include"
-internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.17763.0\\ucrt" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.17763.0\\shared"
-internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.17763.0\\um" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.17763.0\\winrt"
-internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.17763.0\\cppwinrt" -fdeprecated-macro
-fdebug-compilation-dir "D:\\llvm-project\\build\\Release\\bin" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 120 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=19.21.27702 -std=c++14 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o "C:\\Users\\krono\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-19d364.o" -x c++ hello.cc 
clang -cc1 version 9.0.0 based upon LLVM 9.0.0svn default target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here: 
 D:\llvm-project\build\Release\lib\clang\9.0.0\include 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\ATLMFC\include 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt
End of search list.
```

Presumably this was because I made some mistake when I built it (I built it with Visual Studio). How can I make it include the correct header files? I'm talking about a permanent solution rather than just overriding the include search path each time I compile.

Some background on this. I am trying to build a C++ program with clang and I get multiple multiply defined symbol errors, like this

```
error LNK2005: "bool const std::_Is_integral<bool>" (??$_Is_integral@_N@std@@3_NB) already defined in ...
```

`std::_Is_integral` is a name defined in the Visual Studio `<type_traits>` header file. I believe that if I could get clang to include `<type_traits>` from the LLVM libcxx project this error would go away.

Answer (score 0):

I have been hit by the same problem on several open source project myself. I do not have the answer but I can possibly give more details on the nature of the problem:

1) The problem is coming from STL headers in VS2019, which use the following constructs:

```
$ grep -r _Is_integral *
include/xtr1common:// STRUCT TEMPLATE _Is_integral
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral = // determine whether cv-unqualified type _Ty is integral
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral = false; // determine whether cv-unqualified type argument is integral
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<bool> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<char> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<signed char> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<unsigned char> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<wchar_t> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<char16_t> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<char32_t> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<short> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<unsigned short> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<int> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<unsigned int> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<long> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<unsigned long> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<long long> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_integral<unsigned long long> = true;
include/xtr1common:_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool is_integral_v = _Is_integral<remove_cv_t<_Ty>>; // determine whether _Ty is integral
```

The behavior is related to how "if constexpr" is evaluted by the compiler. According to the standard it should be supported from C++17, but MSVC compiler silently supports it when running (in default) C++14 mode.

`clang-cl` on the other hand does not generate C++17 code, when run in C++14 mode, so it generates all those exported symbols and then lets the (MS) linker complain about them.

The solution I found so far (which may or may not be applicable depending on the project) is forcing `clang-cl` into C++17, which then compiles the constructs using "if constexpr" correctly (with no symbols).

The other temporary workaround may be using `/force:multiple` in linker flags to force the linking. Since their values should not change, the multiple definition should not be problem, but it is also suboptimal.

Apparently, MS is aware of the problem, but do not want to change the library.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/426829/xtgmathh-and-other-microsoft-include-files-use-if.html

Concerning the usage of Clang's "native" STL, I would expect one would need to use also "native" `clang` (i.e. not `clang-cl`, which is drop down replacement for MSVC). How this might go then however I have no idea.